# BBP formula for $e$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

For the number $\pi$ we can use the BBP formula to find a sequence of digit starting from the digit $n$, simply using the formula:
$$\displaystyle\pi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{16^k}\left(\dfrac{4}{8k+1}-\dfrac{2}{8k+4}-\dfrac{1}{8k+5}-\dfrac{1}{8k+6}\right).$$
Is there any similar formula able to calculate the $k$ digits after the $n^{th}$ for the base of natural logarithms $e$? Thanks

Comment: I think this has been asked before and the answer turned out to be no, at least to our current knowledge.

Comment: @Ian: 'no', means it's impossible or it's possible to find it, but we still don't know it?

Comment: Just to our current knowledge, not that there's been a proof that no such "spigot algorithm" exists.

Comment: Question was asked (but not answered) here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719665/the-digits-of-pi-and-e

Comment: There are two quite interesting facts about $e$:
1) the measure of irrationality of $e$ is equal to 2 (as if $e$ were algebraic instead of transcendent);
2) continued fraction of $e$ shows some “regularity”
$$e=[2; 1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8, 1,1 ,10,1,1,12,1,1,14,11,…..,1,1,2n,1,1,….]$$ 
I doubt it's impossible to find a BBP formula for $e$.

Comment: Searching Math Reviews online for bbp turns up many papers evaluating many constants, but no mention of $e$. That doesn't prove it's impossible, or even that it's unknown, but it does seem to be hiding.

Comment: David Bailey writes, in http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/bbp-formulas.pdf, "as far as anyone can tell (although this has not
been rigorously proven), $e$ is not a polylogarithmic constant in the sense of this paper, and thus it and its powers are not expected to satisfy BBP-type linear relations (this assumption is confirmed by extensive experience using the author's PSLQ programs)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *sort-of* BBP type formula for $e$ that I found is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k \cdot \frac{4k+3}{(4k+2)\cdot((2k)!)}\right)$$
As you may have noticed, though, there is a factorial ($!$), so it isn't computationally efficient and will cause overflows, resulting in inaccurate results. It does, however, work.

Comment: Please note that this is not a *proper* BBP formula, but can still be used in the digit-extraction algorithm.